# Unable to Drag and Drop files/directories from local Mac (High Sierra) to remote Mac (Mojave) via screenshare

Tags: macos, permission, remote-desktop, screen-sharing, file-transfer

I have a user who cannot drag and drop files from her local Mac (High Sierra) to her remote Mac (Mojave). She can copy and paste text but not transfer files. It comes up with a small grey forbidden icon but no error message. She says that she used to be able to do this but has at some point lost functionality.

If I log into a screen share session with my user it's no problem to drag and drop files.

Do you know where to start looking for clues on how to fix this issue? Is there a setting on her local machine preventing this, is it a permissions issue or is there somewhere else I can look?